Writing to a Kafka topic is taking time and producer timing out
We have an issue where producer is timing out writing to a kafka topic. The timeout set is 30 seconds. I dont see any specific errors related to the topic in kafka logs but i see the below errors during that time. What could be the issue ? How can i go about debugging this ?
[2024-04-25 12:59:58,100] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group robot.topo.svc.to.colln.mgr in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 390312 (__consumer_offsets-1) (reason: error when storing group assignment during SyncGroup (member: consumer-robot.topo.svc.to.colln.
[2024-04-25 12:59:58,107] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group robot.topo.svc.to.colln.mgr generation 390313 (__consumer_offsets-1) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-25 12:59:58,120] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group robot.topo.svc.to.colln.mgr for generation 390313 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-25 12:59:58,188] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group optima-engine-56-icon-group in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 45137 (__consumer_offsets-13) (reason: error when storing group assignment during SyncGroup (member: rdkafka-986ea7a0-1927-4b68-af64-0
[20

We tried to restart Kafka increase the timeout for replication threads. At this point we are stuck on how to proceed further. Any help is greatly appreciated.
